# IsMatch method returns false when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string and regex to get parameter from it. Here's the message:

> "Data Flow Task:Error: There was an error with Insert Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[EmissionMarket] on Insert Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: \"The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.\"."

Here's the regexp:

> {Data Flow Task:Error: There was an error with Insert Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[(.*?)] on Insert Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".}

(both strings are copied from VS during runtime, so quotas and square brackets are from VS)

I can't see any reason why they can not match, but IsMatch method returns false. What am I missing?

Comment: Hint: You need to escape some of those characters.

Comment: `[]`s should be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the "[" and "]" characters. You need to escape those for your regular expression, otherwise they are considered character classes. In other words you need:

```
Data Flow Task:Error: There was an error with Insert Destination.Inputs\[OLE DB Destination Input\].Columns\[(.*?)\] on Insert Destination.Inputs\[OLE DB Destination Input\]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions use `[` and `]` to form character classes. You need to escape at least the `[` character as `\[`. You also need to escape all instances of `.` which you mean a literal period (using `\.` instead), or it will allow matching any character at that location.

For more information, see [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot, missed that aspect

Answer (score 1):

You need to scape several characters

Both   `.` and `[]` has a special meaning in regex and in general all characters that has it needs to be escaped `\`

Based on your sample the result will be something like:

```
"Data Flow Task:Error: There was an error with Insert Destination\.Inputs\[OLE DB Destination Input\]\.Columns\[(.*?)\] on Insert Destination\.Inputs\[OLE DB Destination Input\]\. The column status returned was\: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column\."\.
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dF8fL5/1)